# Using google sheets as a database authenticating from the code

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a POC (a Vue based web application) for which I require a database. I want to use the google sheet as a database

I followed the official **Google Sheets API v4** documentation and I am able to perform all kinds of database operations on the google sheet. But, it requires the user to explicitly click on a button and sign in to authenticate. I want it to be done from the code itself.

I have the following keys which are required along with the user consent to use the google sheets API

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';
```

Apart from this I also have a `client secret` which I have absolutely no idea how to use it in the code. From what I have read over the internet and what I have understood, it is used to authenticate the access to google sheets API from the code. But, I don't know how.

I did come across some of the third-party services like [Sheetsu](https://sheetsu.com/sheets-javascript) and [SheetDB](https://sheetdb.io/) which I don't want to use. So, is there a way I can use google sheets as a database for simple CRUD operations just as we will do with any traditional database?

Comment: Not personally familiar, but what happens on click? can this not be simulated by sending the credentials on some internal event?

Comment: On click, it opens the google authentication popup where you sign in to your google account. Then you get the access token which is sed to perform API requests to the google sheets API

Comment: And all this is taken care of google API library. So, I don't think it could be simulated in any way

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving that way - expecting a user to authenticate - because you are using OAuth2 authentication which is meant for scenarios where a user grants your program access to their spreadsheet.

For your scenario you want to use the other type of authentication: service account.

Actually, you can use a service account with OAuth, as described here:
Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

And you could consider this because the code examples tend to use OAuth, but I'm suggesting that you instead go back to the sheets API in the console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/credentials?project=yourProjectId

And click 'create credentials' and choose a service account instead of OAuth.  This method  has a simpler authentication flow since it is meant for your scenario: no end-user.

Also, I haven't done this in a while, but I think I took the service account client_email (the email address of the account - the main identifier) and give it permission to access the sheet, ie. share your sheet with it.

Finally, I would note - and you probably already know this - but you mention using sheets like a database and it doesn't have the performance characteristics for this.  It is more like a CRM: eg. suitable for a building a static site.

Comment: I got this that we need to use a service account in such type of scenario. And there are lot of tutorials available for the same in python, PHP , node. But, I want to do it from the frontend (a Vuejs application)

Comment: Oh, when you wrote about accessing your own sheet (as a db) directly from the code, I imagined that you must be talking about the server side of your app.  I doubt there is any secure way to do what you are talking about from the client - you would be giving out a script for anyone to access your DB.  I think you may need to move your sheet access to the server.